# App crashing due to missing Microsoft.VC80.CRT v8.0.50727.6195

Tags: .net, assemblies, side-by-side

I wrote a C# application to grab images from a firewire camera. I have installed the camera vendor's SDK which includes firewire driver and the SDK dlls (.NET).The SDK dlls are deployed in GAC during the installation.

The SDK dll that I referenced in my application has a dependency on Microsoft.VC80.CRT v8.0.50727.6195. I copied the manifest file and the dlls msvcr80.dll, msvcm80.dll & msvcp80.dll to the same folder as my application and I tried running my application but still .NET runtime was unable to locate the VCRT dll and my app is crashing.

I get the below exception:
"Could not load file or assembly 'CameraSDK.dll' or one of its dependencies. The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)."

I have googled and found that I needed to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 to get the VCRT v8.0.50727.6195. I downloaded and tried to install the VCRedist but it didn't install the dlls. My machine has both VS2008 and VS2010 and I presume that the VCRedist installer found a much latest version on my machine and it skipped the installation.

How can I get my application to look for the dependent dlls in the local directory? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the vcredist_x64.EXE from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26347 just did not appear in my list of installed programs although there was no error message during installation. I tried vcredist_x86.EXE and this did the trick.